# How to list multiple purposes for an action?

Tags: grammar, reason

So, one of the example sentences for ため that I see in the learning software I use is:

> 彼女はダイエットのために泳いでいる。

Which basically means, "She swims in order to lose weight."

But what if you wanted to say, "She swims in order to lose weight, and for fun?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a common way of speaking to tell somebody does something with multiple purposes.

> 彼女はダイエット**と**趣味**を兼【か】ねて**水泳をしている。

**[兼ねる](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AD%E3%82%8B)**

> <sub>Ichidan verb, Transitive verb</sub>
>   2. to serve two or more functions or roles simultaneously; to contain (or combine) two or more features

Answer (score 2):

You can use "と" like ダイエットと楽しみのために.